# In "Million Dollar Baby", could old Morgan Freeman really knock out that young punk in the ring?

Tags: realism, million-dollar-baby

In *Million Dollar Baby*, there is a scene where Eddie "Scrap Iron" Dupris(Morgan Freeman) decides to teach a lesson to some young boxers at the gym who are picking on a weaker, less-experienced boxer. Eddie is old, blind in one eye, appears to have not boxed nor trained for years, and only puts on one glove. Is it realistic that he could have knocked out the young, fit, up-and-coming boxer punk within just a few seconds, with just 3 punches? Did it help that he hit the kid with his ungloved fist?

The match starts at 2:20 in this clip.

Comment: Morgan Freeman is 'the president' & 'god'. Of course he can knock out any punk he likes ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If the boxer was a professional one, even a bad professional it's extremely unlikely.

If he was an amateur then yes, [check what this 72 year old man did to a thief](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-1196479/Pictured-The-battered-bruised-face-burglar-got-wrong-72-year-old-boxer.html).

If I remember the film correctly it's unknown if he was a pro boxer or not.

Comment: Thanks. That story about the 72-year-old definitely makes the case!

Comment: I was loling all throughout reading that article. Just gave him the ol' one-two.. bop bop!